# Create SQL Server procedure in a transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I need to create two procedures in a SQL Server transaction. If failure, I need to rollback the create(s) and any other executed queries in this transaction. I know the create statement must be the first statement in query batch, but I need to know how handle the transaction with multiple batches.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_SP-1]
    @id BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- SQL statements 
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_SP-2]
    @id BIGINT  
AS  
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- SP-2 statements
END
GO

UPDATE Table 
SET Value = '1.0.0.5' 

COMMIT TRANSACTION / ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Comment: **Side note**: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: thanks for this note, i will keep this in my mind ,, Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is one method to execute multiple batches in a transaction. This uses a temp table to indicate if any batch erred and perform a final `COMMIT` or `ROLLLBACK` accordingly.

Another method is to encapsulate statements that must be in single-statement batch (`CREATE PROCEDURE`, `CREATE VIEW`, etc.) but that can get rather ugly when quotes within the literal text must be escaped.

```
CREATE TABLE #errors (error varchar(5));
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_SP-1]
    @id bigint 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- SP Statments 
END;
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 INSERT INTO #errors VALUES('error');
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_SP-2]
     @id BIGINT  
AS  
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- SP-2 Statments
END;
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 INSERT INTO #errors VALUES('error');
GO

UPDATE Table SET Value='1.0.0.5' 
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 INSERT INTO #errors VALUES('error');
GO

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #errors)
BEGIN
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 COMMIT;
END;
GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#errors', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #errors;
GO
```

Comment: Thank you sir , i think it is perfect one

Comment: @ayman2000, if this works for you, please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I think it needs to modifay 
BEGIN
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 COMMIT;
END;
i think it need to modifay to 
 IF @@TRANCOUNT =  0 COMMIT;

Comment: @ayman2000, one cannot COMMIT or ROLLBACK unless `@@TRANCOUNT  > 0`. I changed the script to remove the TRY/CATCH around the update and use `@@ERROR` instead so that compile errors within that batch can be detected and the script with work regardless of the  `XACT_ABORT` session setting.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to study more about this subject in [Handling Transactions in Nested SQL Server Stored Procedures](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4897/handling-transactions-in-nested-sql-server-stored-procedures/).

From the beginning, your syntax is wrong. You cannot begin a transaction and then create a procedure, you need to do just the opposite:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_SP-1]
@id bigint  
AS
BEGIN

   BEGIN TRY

      BEGIN TRANSACTION

           SET NOCOUNT ON;
        -- SP-2 Statments

          Update Table set Value='1.0.0.5'

   END TRY

   BEGIN CATCH 
    --handle error and perform rollback
         ROLLBACK  
      SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
      SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage   
   END CATCH
END
```

It is best practice to use `TRY` and `CATCH` when attempting to perform update inside transaction scope.

Please read more and investigate using the link I provided to get a bigger picture.

Comment: I think he wants to use transaction for DDL not DML‌ commands

Comment: and yet still, the syntax is incorrect altogether regardless of what command he is trying to achieve, he'll need to create two different transactions for each procedure.

Comment: @AfshinAmiri, the transaction only work in DML only. Also, it uses the Update statement with setting a column value, so it is not DDL.

Comment: thanks @Ajay2707c I didn't want to focus on that remark as it is not connected to the op question and will only confuse him further.

Comment: you put the transaction into Procedure, what i need to do is put the procedures into a transaction

Answer (score 1):

To use Transaction, you need to know what is the meaning of transaction. It's meaning of 'Unit of work either in commit state or rollback state'.

So when you use transaction, you must know that where you declare and where you close. So you must start and end transaction in the parent procedure only than it will work as a unit of work i.e. whatever no of query execute of DML statement, it uses the same transaction.

I do not understand why your update statement outside of procedure and transaction portion too.

It should be (See my comments, you can use TRY Catch same as c sharp) :

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_SP-1]
    @id bigint 
  AS
  BEGIN
   Begin Transaction
     SET NOCOUNT ON;

            -- SP Statments 
            Exec SP_SP-2 @id    --here you can pass the parameter to another procedure, but do not use transaction in another procedure, other wise it will create another transaction
    If @@Error > 0 than
        Rollback 
    Else
        Commit
    End
   END


 GO

 --Do not use transaction in another procedure, otherwise, it will create another transaction which has own rollback and commit and do not participate in the parent transaction
  Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_SP-2]
     @id BIGINT  
    AS  
      BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      -- SP-2 Statments

       END
  GO
```

Comment: I Find the Solution of this to Execute the procedures as Execution script i will put the solution into a comment

Comment: sorry execution script ? can you post your code @ayman2000, so it will help else also

Comment: what i need to make many tasks into on patch files, first i need to create procedures and update statements ...this update statements not related to procedures ...one patch upgrade file contains many tasks and if any error happened i need to rolleback all changes done in this patch file

Answer (score 0):

i find this solution to execute the procedure as string execution , it`s a workaround to execute what i want

```
Begin Try
 Begin Transaction
        EXEC ('
                 Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_1]
                     @id bigint 

                         AS
                             BEGIN  
                      SET NOCOUNT ON;
                                    SP-1
                                 END
                         GO
                   Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Inc_Discovery_RunDoc]
                       @id bigint
                             AS
                       BEGIN    
                              SET NOCOUNT ON;
                                     Sp-2
                              END')
 Update Table set Value='1.0.0.5' 
Commit  
End Try
 Begin Catch
Rollback  
Declare @Msg nvarchar(max)
Select @Msg=Error_Message();
RaisError('Error Occured: %s', 20, 101,@Msg) With Log;
End Catch
```

Comment: this is not the good thing @ayman2000, this is used to create a procedure in the transaction after procedure create it will work independently

Comment: @Ajay2707, this will not work because `GO` is not a T-SQL statement and will err when executed. `GO` is a batch terminator recognized by SQL Server tools and some of their APIs (SMO methods). You could use separate `EXEC` statements for each proc, but as I mentioned in my answer, it will get ugly when you need to escape quotes within the proc text,